# British versus American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Anyone know how much of the world uses British versus American English?

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on [linguistics.se](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: why?

Comment: @Marthaª: Because linguists are better-qualified to answer this question, which is relatively important to their field. US/UK differences are only peripherally relevant to ELU - often simply because it can unexpectedly turn out that competent speakers on both sides of the Atlantic disagree about "standard" usage. I know linguistics.se is still in beta, but they'll hardly be helped by you suggesting that something like this question is better suited to ELU than to their more expert pronouncements.

Comment: [not off-topic] ≠ [better suited]. IOW I don't think we should close questions that are on-topic just because they're maybe-perhaps *more* on-topic somewhere else. (I'm declining at this point to decide whether this question *is*, in fact, more on-topic on Linguistics.)

Comment: @Marthaª: How you could entertain the possibility that this question is *more* on-topic here than on linguistics is beyond me, but as ever, we have our different opinions. And with 2 upvotes for your comment, against 2 closevotes added to mine, we've obviously split the community right down the middle! I still won't agree if it goes against me, but I'm a democrat so I believe in the process.

Comment: I would say it's off-topic here because statistics on population are not on-topic.

Comment: This is totally on-topic. The US/UK/et al. difference are __centrally__ relevant here, even where the difference is vague. This is possibly [general reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Countries_in_order_of_total_speakers), but still worth some kind of answer with nuance here (like are those figures accurate for counting what is AmE and what is BrE). By your reasoning, any question about any word difference between AmE and BrE is off-topic, which is obviously contrary to experience here.

Comment: @Mitch The question is not about any word difference between  American English, and in British English; the question is about how much people use British English, and how much people use American English. The topic on EL&U is English, not the people speaking English.

Answer (score 3):

It depends to a large extent on how you define the terms, but the United States has over 200 million people who speak English as a first language and over 30 million who speak it as a second language. The figures for the UK are 57 million and 1 million. (Source: [‘The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521736501).) It’s difficult to know to what extent the same proportions exist in the wider world, particularly since there are parts of the English-speaking world that speak neither, but I would guess that American English predominates.

Comment: I'm thinking he means geographically, as opposed to numerically.  For example, do Australians use British English, or American English?  What about Canadians?  And, if they use "neither," does that mean they are using, say, Canadian English?  Or simply a mixture of British and American English?

Comment: @J.R. I have taken varieties such as Australian English and Canadian English to be discrete. They may share some features with British or American English, but their accents alone set them apart. As I said, it depends on how you define your terms. Even then, the relevant data might be very hard to collect.

Answer (score 1):

How people speak sometimes depends on who they are talking to. I used to think my English is more American because of the books I read and television influence, since I enjoy more American authors and TV programs than British ones.  Nowadays in Singapore I believe we speak a number of variations of English and switch between them quite unconsciously; like someone who reads lips and is hard of hearing will (I believe) have to adjust how she reads, depending who is speaking to her.  Otherwise there will be more misreadings.

As Singaporeans, we find many friends switching to another accent, or even different sentence structures, just because the person they are talking to is Caucasian, or Japanese; but with Singaporeans it depends.  If it were at the supermarket or a street open air food court, I think its global multi-English.  Not only Singlish but a sensitivity towards different speakers makes me a multi-English speaker.  When I write I use different styles if it's for different publications.